# Shifting leading NA cells to the left, but NOT internal NAs in R

Tags: r, dplyr, na, zoo

As a preface, I've noticed that there are at least 5 answers to a similar question, "How do I shift non-NA cells leftward." There are many good answers for this, and the zoo package has a na.locf() that does it well.

My particular issue is that I want to shift the cells to the right of the final leading NA leftward, replacing all leading NAs. This means that I need to retain "internal" and trailing NAs. Here's a small example with a matrix, but my real data is a large data.frame:

```
matrixtest[1, 1:3] <- NA
matrixtest[3, 1:2] <- NA
matrixtest[2, 3] <- NA
matrixtest[4, 2] <- NA
matrixtest

matrixresult <-matrix(4, ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
matrixresult[1, 2:4] <- NA
matrixresult[3, 3:4] <- NA
matrixresult[2, 3] <- NA
matrixresult[4, 2] <- NA
matrixresult
```

After manipulation the `matrixtest` original should look like the `matrixresult`
as such:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA    4
[2,]    4    4   NA    4
[3,]   NA   NA    4    4
[4,]    4   NA    4    4
> matrixresult
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    4    4   NA    4
[3,]    4    4   NA   NA
[4,]    4   NA    4    4
```

Apologies if I've missed an applicable answer already. I've spent too much time on this seemingly simple problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how your example works?

Comment: Col 1:4 represent quarters of a year. I'm trying to align everyone's measurement with their first, second, third, etc. time being measured, rather than aligning them by the calendar.
`matrixtest <- matrix(4, ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
matrixtest[1, 1:3] <- NA
matrixtest[3, 1:2] <- NA
matrixtest[2, 3] <- NA
matrixtest[4, 2] <- NA
matrixtest

matrixresult <-matrix(4, ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
matrixresult[1, 2:4] <- NA
matrixresult[3, 3:4] <- NA
matrixresult[2, 3] <- NA
matrixresult[4, 2] <- NA
matrixresult

zoomat <- zoo(matrixtest)
zoomat <- na.locf(zoomat, fromLast = T)
`

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite know this markdown. But if you run the above code with appropriate line breaks to make it readable, you get a matrix unlike the matrix named `matrixtest` above. I think I'm clearly explaining, but please let me know if I can help further.

Answer (score 1):

We create an index based on the last column and `rev`erse those rows

```
i1 <- is.na(matrixresult[, ncol(matrixresult)])
matrixresult[i1, ] <- t(apply(matrixresult[i1,], 1, rev))
```

-output

```
matrixresult
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA    4
#[2,]    4    4   NA    4
#[3,]   NA   NA    4    4
#[4,]    4   NA    4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** `shiftLeft` removes the NAs off the ends in its input `x` using `na.trim` giving `y` and then overwrites the beginning of a vector of NAs with that.  `apply` that to every row and transpose that since `apply` results in the transpose of what we want.

```
library(zoo)

shiftLeft <- function(x, y = na.trim(x)) replace(NA * x, seq_along(y), y)
m <- t(apply(matrixtest, 1, shiftLeft))

# check 
identical(m, matrixresult)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** An alternate which is a bit longer but only involves base R is:

```
shiftLeft2 <- function(x) {
  ix <- which.max(!is.na(x))
  replace(NA*x, seq_len(length(x) - ix + 1), x[ix:length(x)])
}
m2 <- t(apply(matrixtest, 1, shiftLeft2))
```

### Note

We used the first matrix as input and the second to check against.

```
matrixtest <- structure(c(NA, 4, NA, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))

matrixresult <- structure(c(4, 4, 4, 4, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 4, NA, 
4), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
```